# In a user namespace as non-root, on a nosuid,nodev filesystem, why does a bind mount succeed but a remount fails?

Tags: linux, namespace, readonly, bind-mount, non-root-user

In a Linux user namespace, as non-root, I bind mount `/tmp/foo` to itself.  This succeeds.

Then, I try to remount `/tmp/foo` to be read-only.  If `/tmp` is mounted with `nosuid` or `nodev`, then the remount fails.  Otherwise, the remount succeeds.

Is there some reason why `nosuid` and/or `nodev` prevent the remount from succeeding?  Is this behavior documented somewhere?  I'm puzzled, as I would expect the bind mount and remount to either both succeed, or both fail.

Here is the code to reproduce the bind mount and remount:

```
#define   _GNU_SOURCE      /*  unshare   */
#include  <errno.h>        /*  errno     */
#include  <sched.h>        /*  unshare   */
#include  <stdio.h>        /*  printf    */
#include  <string.h>       /*  strerror  */
#include  <sys/mount.h>    /*  mount     */
#include  <unistd.h>       /*  getuid    */

int main() {

  printf ( "getuid   %d\n", getuid() );

  int rv = unshare ( CLONE_NEWNS | CLONE_NEWPID | CLONE_NEWUSER );
  printf ( "unshare  %2d  %s\n", rv, strerror(errno) );

  rv = mount ( "/tmp/foo", "/tmp/foo", 0, MS_BIND | MS_REC, 0 ),
  printf ( "mount    %2d  %s\n", rv, strerror(errno) );

  rv = mount ( "/tmp/foo", "/tmp/foo", 0,
               MS_BIND | MS_REMOUNT | MS_RDONLY, 0 ),
  printf ( "remount  %2d  %s\n", rv, strerror(errno) );

  return  0;

}
```

Sample output:

```
$  mkdir -p /tmp/foo
$  mount | grep /tmp
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,inode64)
$  gcc test.c && ./a.out
getuid   1000
unshare   0  No error information
mount     0  No error information
remount  -1  Operation not permitted
$  uname -a
Linux hostname 5.12.12_1 #1 SMP 1624132767 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Whereas, if `/tmp` is mounted with neither `nosuid` nor `nodev`, then the bind mount and the remount will both succeed, as follows:

```
$  mkdir -p /tmp/foo
$  mount | grep /tmp
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime,inode64)
$  gcc test.c && ./a.out
getuid   1000
unshare   0  No error information
mount     0  No error information
remount   0  No error information
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer.

As can be seen in the below excerpts from the kernel source code, if any of the flags NODEV, NOSUID, NOEXEC, and/or ATIME are already set, I will need to preserve (i.e. continue to set) them in my second call to `mount()`.

From `fs/namespace.c` in the Linux kernel source code:

```
/*
 * Handle reconfiguration of the mountpoint only without alteration of the
 * superblock it refers to.  This is triggered by specifying MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND
 * to mount(2).
 */
static int do_reconfigure_mnt(struct path *path, unsigned int mnt_flags)
{
        struct super_block *sb = path->mnt->mnt_sb;
        struct mount *mnt = real_mount(path->mnt);
        int ret;

        if (!check_mnt(mnt))
                return -EINVAL;

        if (path->dentry != mnt->mnt.mnt_root)
                return -EINVAL;

        if (!can_change_locked_flags(mnt, mnt_flags))
                return -EPERM;

        down_write(&sb->s_umount);
        ret = change_mount_ro_state(mnt, mnt_flags);
        if (ret == 0)
                set_mount_attributes(mnt, mnt_flags);
        up_write(&sb->s_umount);

        mnt_warn_timestamp_expiry(path, &mnt->mnt);

        return ret;
}


static bool can_change_locked_flags(struct mount *mnt, unsigned int mnt_flags)
{
        unsigned int fl = mnt->mnt.mnt_flags;

        if ((fl & MNT_LOCK_READONLY) &&
            !(mnt_flags & MNT_READONLY))
                return false;

        if ((fl & MNT_LOCK_NODEV) &&
            !(mnt_flags & MNT_NODEV))
                return false;

        if ((fl & MNT_LOCK_NOSUID) &&
            !(mnt_flags & MNT_NOSUID))
                return false;

        if ((fl & MNT_LOCK_NOEXEC) &&
            !(mnt_flags & MNT_NOEXEC))
                return false;

        if ((fl & MNT_LOCK_ATIME) &&
            ((fl & MNT_ATIME_MASK) != (mnt_flags & MNT_ATIME_MASK)))
                return false;

        return true;
}
```